# How would I format a list of dates within a struts 2 select tag?

Tags: java, date, select, struts2, tags

I am trying to format dates within a struts 2 select tag but I am having difficulty doing so. I know there is a struts 2 date tag but I don't think that is what I am looking for.

What I am doing here is populating a select box with a list of (week end)dates where I can choose which dates to add to an employee's time off sheet. Basically I am trying to format them so that it shows up nice and neat (MM/dd/yyyy) but I can't seem to find the correct way to do this. I have tried inserting a  format tag in between my list below, I have tried using a format.date parameter in the tag, and I have tried using listValue to format the dates but nothing seems to be working. Am I missing something here?

`<s:select size="25" id="inputExclusionDates" name="available" list="availableExclusions" multiple="true" cssClass="multi-select" />`

Comment: The "availableExclusions" is a list of dates? What values your want to show and what values your whant to use as select value? (listKey="what is here?" listValue="what is here?")

Comment: You win a +1 because for no other reason than you're the 3000 question! Now I'll read the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fun I took the time to figure out how to do this in OGNL which was not as easy as I expected because of some strange wrinkle.

The following works with an action which supplies a java.text.SimpleDateFormat property called simpleDateFormat (Note the only part that is different in these select tags is the listValue property):

```
<s:select listValue="simpleDateFormat.format(new java.util.Date(#this[0].time))" size="25" id="inputExclusionDates" name="available" list="availableExclusions" multiple="true" cssClass="multi-select" />
```

The following does the same as the above but does everything in the JSP:

```
<s:select listValue="(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy')).format(new java.util.Date(#this[0].time))" size="25" id="inputExclusionDates" name="available" list="availableExclusions" multiple="true" cssClass="multi-select" />
```

Now I mentioned a wrinkle, those with good eyes will have noted the seemingly redundant expression `new java.util.Date(#this[0].time)` after all I should just be able to say `#this[0]`.  That would make sense after all but it does not work. So since this confused me somewhat I'll ask a question about it: [Strange OGNL behaviour when using #this in s:select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474967/strange-ognl-behaviour-when-using-this-in-sselect)

Comment: Quaternion, that is awesome! It worked like a charm. I know I could have done this on the back end but I knew there had to be a way to do this, I was just surprised that I couldn't find anything at all about it or no one had asked before. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way to format date: fill your list with objects with some "format date method" instead of Date.

1 Create class with "format Date" method

```
public class MyDate {
  private Date date;

  public Date getDate(){
    return date;
  }

  public String getFormatedDate(){
    String str = **some code to format date**;
    return  str;
  }
```

2 Put this objects in the availableExclusions list

3

```
<s:select size="25" id="inputExclusionDates" name="available" list="availableExclusions" multiple="true" cssClass="multi-select" listKey="date" listValue="formatedDate"/>
```

Comment: This probably is the easiest way... I would add a get/set for a java.text.DateFormat property or more likely in your case a java.text.SimpleDateFormat so you can easily set the format you want.