# Strange OGNL behaviour when using #this in s:select

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

Consider the following where availableExclusions is an array of Date objects.

```
<s:select listValue="(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy')).format(new java.util.Date(#this[0].time))" size="25" id="inputExclusionDates" name="available" list="availableExclusions" multiple="true" cssClass="multi-select" />
```

I created the above in response to this question [How would I format a list of dates within a struts 2 select tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454517/how-would-i-format-a-list-of-dates-within-a-struts-2-select-tag) (and I also recommended that the other solution may be the better way to go). Regardless if using such long OGNL expression is a good idea or not, I can't see the need for: `new java.util.Date(#this[0].time)` despite creating that fragment out of frustration and to my surprise found it worked where the seemingly equivalent `#this[0]` did not (produced no output).

If we substitute in `listValue="#this[0].class"` we see what we would expect: `class java.util.Date`

Creating a new Date behaves as expected, and calling the deprecated properties of Date such as `listValue="#this[0].day"` produces the expected output.

**Why must I use the redundant expression** `new java.util.Date(#this[0].time)` **instead of** `#this[0]` **in this select statement?**

Using Struts 2.3.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `#this[0]` is automatically converted to String. If you turn log level to debug you can see an exception message that's normally suppressed.